# How To fix clipping issue with a trench coat on a model?

Tags: mesh, vertices, clipping

[image: The knees]

Working on a few low-poly placeholder models for my friend's game and no matter what I do, this long trench coat keeps clipping on the knees, i tired messing around with weight paiting for a good half hour.
Is there a way to PIN some of the coat's verticies to the leg?
It's part of the same model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create bones for the coat so it can flow with movement of the character but also not be stuck/limited to moving where the legs are. I'd make two or three sets of bones. One set for the left, middle, and right side of the coat. Number of joints is up to you.

But if you need to limit bones count then apply weights to the coat exactly equal to the legs. It's the only way to prevent clipping but will not look accurate when animated.